# Wrap multiple element

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to wrap multiple elements with jQuery?

```
<div id="container">
    <h3>header</h3>
    <p>content</div>
    <div>some other content</div>
</div>
```

I would like to wrap some content around h3 and p to have something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-1">
           <i class="fas fa-check">
       </div>
       <div class="col-11">
           <h3>header</h3>
           <p>content</div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div>some other content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery provides the `wrapAll` method:

> The .wrapAll() function can take any string or object that could be passed to the $() function to specify a DOM structure. This structure may be nested several levels deep, but should contain only one inmost element. The structure will be wrapped around all of the elements in the set of matched elements, as a single group.
>   http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/

So you can do something like:

```
$('#container').find('h3,p').wrapAll('<div class="col-11"/>');
```

and then use `prepend()` and `wrap()` to put your add other elements to your `row` div.

Answer (score 2):

You can merge jquery objects in shallow jquery object with merge, then clone your selection, remove original, and add the clone to a new element:

```
var jqEl = $.merge( $('h3'), $('p') );
var cloneJq = jqEl.clone();

jqEl.remove();
$("#container").append($("<div class='col-xs-12' />").html(cloneJq));
```

Answer (score 2):

That could be achieved using **[`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)** and **[`prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/)** like :

```js
var target = $("h3,p");
var extra_div = $('<div class="col-1">').append('<i class="fas fa-check"/>');

target.wrapAll($('<div class="row"/>'));
target.wrapAll($('<div class="col-11"/>'));
$(extra_div).prependTo($(".row"));

console.log($('#container')[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <h3>header</h3>
  <p>content</p>
  <div>some other content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you do this like that using jquery

```
        var container = $('#container').html();
        $('#container').html('<div class="row">' +
            '   <div class="col-1">' +
            '       <i class="fas fa-check">' +
            '   </div>' +
            '   <div class="col-11">');
        $('#container').append(container);
        $('#container p').after('</div>');
        $('#container').append('</div>');
```

this is the code on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u6kp0fto/